# Two Necromancer badges for one question?

Tags: support, badges

I seem to have unintentionally created a small badge-factory for myself with my question on tracing `pgfkeys`.  After I posted my solution, I got a few votes and that gave me a Necromancer badge.  Today, Andrew Stacey bumped it with an edit, and as a result it got a few more votes, going past 10...and earning me a second Necromancer.  Is this behavior intentional?  One Necromancer per every 5 votes for an answer *originally* posted more than 30 days later?

Comment: The [revision history](http://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/43662/1) of your first answer shows you answered it on Feb 7 at 6:43 - is this not correct?

Comment: Also, [Necromancer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/17/necromancer?userid=575) badges are for *answers*, so your two answers meet the criteria.

Comment: Of course, I have two answers.  How silly of me.  Now I can blame the people who voted up the CW answer with nothing in it :)

Comment: No worries - thank you for going back and actually answering your question!

Comment: I think that you should write a new answer to that question explaining the situation ... then we can vote for that too and get you a third badge.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You got two badges because you wrote two answers, and both qualify for that badge.

Comment: That somehow did not occur to me.  I wrote off the CW answer entirely in my mind :)